# Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Boolean'

Tags: vb.net, strict

```
        If result12.Contains("""Status"" value=""0""") Then
        TextBox1.Text = "Antique Lights are On" And
        Label19.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
```

I can not figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I just want the text box to show "Antique Lights are On".  I keep getting an error about converting to Boolean.  Shouldn't it stay string?  I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and creating a windows form.

Comment: What is that AND at the end of the TextBox1.Text line?

Comment: I have it changing the text color as well. Do I not need the And?

Comment: Despite your 'noobishness', I applaud you for using Option Strict. Well done that man, keep up the good work!

Comment: No you don't. Just make it a seperate line inside of your conditional statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
TextBox1.Text = "Antique Lights are On" And
Label19.ForeColor = Color.Red
```

Starting in VS 2012, you didn't have to include the underscore for a line continuation in VB.NET.

So this is interpreted as boolean statement:

```
"Antique Lights are On" And Label19.ForeColor = Color.Red
```

Since `"Antique Lights are On"` isn't a valid boolean statement you get the error.

Comment: [Implicit Line Continuation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/we86c8x2(v=vs.100).aspx) was VS2010

Comment: @Plutonix - Thanks for the clarification. I could have sworn it was 2012, but I must have just never used it in 2010. Old habits die hard...

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the 'And' to process the next line.

'And' in this case is trying to do a boolean conditional, which doesn't make sense in this context.